# Sort Rss feed by date created not date modified

Tags: rss, sorting

The way I'm currently set up with Foundations 2010, the last document I modify is the document at the top of the rss feed, however I'd like the rss feed to sort strictly by order of the date the document was created. I've been looking around and have not found a setting for this anywhere, is there a setting, or do I have edit the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure a view with the sort you want, and use that as your RSS feed. Append:

```
?View=<View ID>
```

You can also get the full URL of the view's RSS by clicking the little RSS icon next to the view's Name in the Edit View page.

I'm not sure there is a way to sort the default feed, it doesn't seem to be using the default view.